# Is it safe to memoize JSX elements to pass them later in props to owned components?

Tags: reactjs

Consider an example:

```
const someElement = <CustomElement value="some" />;

function Foo({ style }) {
  return <Bar style={style}>{someElement}</Bar>;
}
```

Are there any pitfalls if I want to keep passing the same instance of React element as props to children? How normal and acceptable is this specific case for React's reconciliation?

Comment: Why do this?  Do you have massive blocks of unchanging HTML (not even the children vary) and some known performance problem? I.e., are you compelled to stray from the canonical path of componentizing repetetive HTML?

Comment: Yes, you precisely described the situation, albeit I meant not HTML but React Native, but it's not that important. I think I have other workarounds, but I couldn't find anyone who would tell me **purely from a technical standpoint** what are the implications of such a trick.

If we talk about the example above, by reusing `someElement` we make sure that `<Bar>` as a pure component, gets the very same `{ style, children }` and does not need to update, obviously. Of course, I imply that the update inside `<Bar>` is presumed to be heavy in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your approach is sound.  Then again, I'm not sure this will solve your problem; it still has to calculate `someElement`.  I would consider using truly static data (e.g. literal HTML) and I believe React has specific facilities for that (`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?).  Also, note that when Bar updates it still has to do a DOM compare all the way down the tree.  It would not seem that it could know there's something special about `someElement` that would obviate the need to compare that part of the DOM tree.  I think you'd need to at least give the outer tag of your literal a key but this key needn't change unless you repeat the stuff as siblings.  This approach seems fraught even though it may be technically sound.

Another approach that might work is to make it a traditional component but override the method that tells it whether it needs to update.  Obviously, it never needs to update but it would still incur the cost of the initial calculation of the DOM.  I believe your suggestion still incurs that cost, as well.  Maybe a component that does nothing but dangerouslySetInnerHTML and refuses all updates could do the trick; zero calculation.

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer but I think there may be no good reason to depend on the answer.